# Google API does not return the short answer/summary that it shows on the first page

Tags: google-api

Google search has a very useful feature, where it provides a short answer or summary at the top of the search results. eg. If I query "What is the capital of United States ?", it displays a short description of Washington DC and a maps link to Washington DC. However I could not find a way to get this data when using the google custom search API. Does google just not support this or am I missing something ?

Comment: there is no API for that.